# Unauthorized access when calling monero-wallet-rpc

Tags: monerod, daemon, monero-wallet-rpc

I configured the monero RPC with the following command lines:

1/ Firstly I run the monero daemon :
   ./monerod --testnet --rpc-bind-ip=x.x.x.x --rpc-bind-port=28081 --rpc- 
     login user:password --confirm-external-bind

2/Then I configured the monero RPC :
  ./monero-wallet-rpc  --wallet-file testwallet --password test --rpc-bind- 
  port 28082 --rpc-bind-ip=x.x.x.x  --daemon-address x.x.x.x.x:28081 - 
  -testnet --daemon-login user:password --log-level 4 --confirm-external-bind

and the connection is done successfully but when I used it with the CURL it posted a message: "Unauthorized Access".

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either disable RPC authentication (--disable-rpc-login) or give user:password to curl in digest mode.